# upload files - symfony 1.4

Tags: file, symfony-1.4

I need to set a field to be an upload file field just in the backend. I'm not using generator (created the backend like the frontend). How can I do that?
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `sfWidgetFormInputFile` widget, and `sfValidatorFile` validator.

See this page for more info: http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/10

Comment: but the field it's going to be a file upload file both in backend and frontend, isn't it? I want it to be an image in the front, and a file upload in back.

Comment: it worked. thank you. by the way, do you know how to change the browse buttons?

Comment: By default it isn't possible, but maybe http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=browse+button could show some solution?